# Unable to Connect to Hidden Wifi Network (WPA Enterprise, PEAP)

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Please see [here](http://pastebin.com/daRLcZqZ) the entirety of my wireless diagnostics.

I am trying to connect to

> myHiDDenNetWORKssID

which I have created and saved a profile for, as you can see below.

As this is a hidden network, it is not found during scan.

When I try to connect to the hidden network, after some time of trying to connect to it, I get a pop-up that says

> Authentication required by Wi-fi network

This is despite the fact that I have already saved the required credentials in the network profile. In the pop-up, I can see my saved credentials, which I can choose to modify or just click "Connect". Upon clicking "Connect", this pop-up disappears and the whole thing just repeats again and I get another pop-up.

I have tried restarting the NetworkManager service to no avail. Currently, my machine is entirely offline.

When I checked the logs (sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager), I see conflicting information, as follows:

> Oct  5 14:08:13 NetworkManager[2804]:   [1475647693.4282] device
> (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'myHiDDenNetWORKssID' has
> security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
>
> Oct  5 14:08:38> NetworkManager[2804]:   [1475647718.8254] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
>
> Oct  5 14:08:38> NetworkManager[2804]:   [1475647718.8255] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
>
> Oct  5 14:08:38> NetworkManager[2804]:   [1475647718.8277] device > (wlan0):> Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
>
> Oct  5 14:08:38> NetworkManager[2804]:   [1475647718.8301]
> sup-iface[0xfb6b80,wlan0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)

I am really out of ideas as to how to resolve this issue. I have tried various methods, including editing the network profile to IPv6 "Method: Ignore", but nothing works. It continues to ask me for authentication, over and over.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: WPA or WPA/WPA2 mixed mode is known to cause similar issues, particularly when a Broadcom WiFi is involved. Always prefer WPA2 (with AES) only.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I do not see such an available option. I only see "WPA & WPA2 Personal" as well as "WPA & WPA2 Enterprise". Please help!

Comment: Check your router settings, not the clients.